# Finding the general form using undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find the general form of a particular solution using the method of undetermined coefficients of a differential equation?

More specifically for this equation;

$(D^2+4D+5)^2y=x^3e^{-2x}cos(x),D=d/dx$

Comment: Did you calculate the general solution of the homogenous equation ?

Comment: @Peter No, I`m not sure how to do this in this case. I have tried, but the formulation of the equation is what gets me. Frankly I do not know where to begin.

Comment: The second square on the left side is particular confusing.

Comment: I just double checked, that is the question given.

Comment: The second square means apply the differential operator twice: $(d^2/dx^2 + 4d/dx + 5)(d^2/dx^2 + 4d/dx + 5)y$ which expands to $y'''' + 8y''' + 26y'' + 40y' + 25y$